# What to put in OpenShift ConfigMap to get empty string value "" in Jenkins pod template?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, openshift

OpenShift ConfigMap for Jenkins pod template:

```
<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
  <key>vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral</key>
  <value>100Gi</value>
</org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
```

Spits out:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral: "100Gi"
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral: ""
```

But I don't know what to put here:

```
<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
  <key>vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral</key>
  <value>???</value>
</org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
```

These do not seem to work:

```
<value>""</value>
<value>''</value>
<value></value>
<value/>
```

Comment: What if you just remove the entire `<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>` element?

Comment: Then it doesn't include the `vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral` annotation at all. I want the annotation with the empty string `""` as its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `value` tag:

```
<org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
  <key>vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-ephemeral</key>
</org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation>
```

Comment: the only thing i didn't try...

Comment: Glad when I could have helped :)